# How to create a hardware profile in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, profile

Basically reposting from

**How to create a hardware profile in Windows 10**
https://www.techulator.com/experts/5434-How-to-create-a-hardware-profile-in-windows-10

When you use hardware profiles, each time you start your laptop you'll see a menu that prompts you to select a profile configured for the devices at a particular location. Once you select a profile, the operating system will load the drivers needed for the devices connected at that particular location. I.e., Hardware Profile is a .ini file that contains information about the hardware, its settings and instructions for Windows which device to start on Windows start.

After doing a little bit of research, I found that it was easy to do in Windows XP and Windows 7 by using the System Utility in Control Panel, but the same option is no longer present in Windows 8 or Windows 10.

Does anybody know how to create a Hardware profile for a computer by using some inbuilt utility or with the help of a free software?

Comment: It's possible that Windows is smart enough that it no longer needs explicit selection of hardware profiles anymore.