# Setup Windows and apps on a VM then move to PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, disk-image

Is it viable to do it? I'm considering installing and configuring Win10 and all apps I use inside a VM, then create an image of the partition and restore it on my PC.

I'm considering it because my current setup is dated and doing the whole thing takes many days and I can't be without the PC for this long, and I'd rush to do it. But if I do it on a VM, I can keep using the PC during the process and do proper testings.

The issue is that Windows will config itself for the VM hardware, then when moving to my PC it's gonna fret out with the hardware change. Is it able to adapt itself to the new hardware - of course I have all the drivers - and then perform optimistically as if it had been installed on it from start?

Comment: Try VMware Virtual to Physical conversion.  Also consider as a better way (IMHO).  Set up Windows and patch one evening.  Get Office and email running same evening. This is eminently do-able. Day 2 major software.  Also do-able.  Then install as you go. I do this without missing a heartbeat.

Comment: Windows has never and I would argue still not designed to be a portable operating system. There are ways to export your system build certainly but ultimately Windows is installed using that image.

Comment: Thanks I searched for it and it seems to be accounted for in more than 1 solution, I didn't know about it.

Comment: This is just another day in the life a windows admin. Someone has to standardize and image all those thousands of business machines. Yes!!!! You can. Load and configure the vm, sysprep it, capture the image and deploy it to another machine. Load any necessary drivers for the new hardware afterwards. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim?view=windows-11

Comment: @Ramhound Windows has always supported [multiple hardware profiles](https://superuser.com/q/1561112/241386) since at least Win9x. Just select the appropriate profile for the target hardware. Alternatively remove all hardware information to create a common image

Comment: @phuclv - Yes; Sysprep but it’s done well by just transferring the same HDD to around to other systems